How to build wpe GStreamer plugin with Cerbero?
I am building a custom build of GStreamer 1.24.2 for Debian bookworm / arm64 to run in Docker. So far, I managed to build it, and even my application builds and runs fine with it, but I will also need the wpevideosrc plugin for future development. I see that my build does not produce the wpe plugin at all. I can't find any reference to the wpe plugin in the Cerbero repo, which makes me think it is impossible to build this plugin without going the extra mile.
I see that this plugin is installable in Debian via the gstreamer1.0-wpe package, but I can't find how to build it, as I need a different version.
Thanks for any help!
Here's an excerpt from my Dockerfile showing the Cerbero build process.

FROM debian:bookworm

ARG VERSION

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    python3 \
    python3-venv \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-certifi \
    python3-distro \
    python3-pip \
    git

RUN git clone -b ${VERSION} https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero.git

RUN mkdir $HOME/.cerbero && \
    echo "allow_parallel_build=True" > $HOME/.cerbero/cerbero.cbc && \
    echo "use_ccache=True" >> $HOME/.cerbero/cerbero.cbc && \
    cd cerbero && \
        echo "local_sources=\"/cerbero/cerbero-sources\"" > localconf.cbc && \
        echo "home_dir=\"/cerbero/cerbero-build\"" >> localconf.cbc && \
        echo "prefix=\"/usr/local\"" >> localconf.cbc

RUN cd cerbero && \
        ./cerbero-uninstalled -t -c localconf.cbc -c config/cross-lin-arm64.cbc -v norust -v nocdparanoia show-config && \
        ./cerbero-uninstalled -t -c localconf.cbc -c config/cross-lin-arm64.cbc -v norust -v nocdparanoia fetch-bootstrap --jobs=4

RUN cd cerbero && \
        ./cerbero-uninstalled -t -c localconf.cbc -c config/cross-lin-arm64.cbc -v norust -v nocdparanoia fetch-package --jobs=4 gstreamer-1.0

RUN cd cerbero && \
        ./cerbero-uninstalled -t -c localconf.cbc -c config/cross-lin-arm64.cbc -v norust -v nocdparanoia bootstrap -y

RUN cd cerbero && \
        ./cerbero-uninstalled -t -c localconf.cbc -c config/cross-lin-arm64.cbc -v norust -v nocdparanoia package --jobs=4 gstreamer-1.0

# the rest is skipped


